# htaccess issue redirecting certain urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have a bunch of .htaccess rules that follow this format

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lazygamer\.co.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lazygamer.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now I need to put in a new rule to include a category string in my URL and was given this code

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/$ /category/$1/ [R]
```

But it's not being fired for some reason, can someone please show me how to change the above string to match the rule further up.. so I check for some condition before executing the rule?

I only need this rule to fire if the url is in the format http://www.lazygamer.net/post-name/ and not when the url is in the format http://www.lazygamer.net/category/post-name/

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/.*$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ /category/$1/ [R]
```

Comment: No that doesn't seem to make any difference except it breaks my timthumb url calls...?

Comment: I've got my images working again by adding RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images.lazygamer\.net$ [NC] into the rules but my URL's still aren't fixing themselves?

Comment: Okay getting closer, my problem now is that it's adding the category tag to all URL's even if I have a category there already.. The category name is variable as well eg (http://www.lazygamer.net/ps3/rockstar-blames-sony-for-l-a-noire-glitches/) This URL shouldn't be changed as it has PS3 as it's category

Comment: I can live with the double category issue but the big problem now is that I can't view the home page as it keeps adding the generic category onto it

Comment: To solve the last problem I added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$ as a condition and to solve the extra category problem I just added RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-content|wp-admin|wp-includes|fixed|contact-details|advertise|about|category|submission|images|ps3|xbox-

360|wii|other-news|video).*$ in to check for existing categories

Answer (score 1):

My htaccess file now looks like this and solves the problem

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^images.lazygamer\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-content|wp-admin|wp-includes|fixed|contact-details|advertise|about|category|submission|images|ps3|xbox-360|wii|other-news|video).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.lazygamer.net/fixed/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The second last line ignore the root folder which kept me up all night...